# Unique path lifting- Proof clarification

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Below is the proof of the existence of a unique path lifting. [image]

My question is, in the 3rd line from the bottom how is it possible that $\widetilde{f}(s_i)$ belongs to some $V_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $p(\tilde f(s_i))\in U$ implies that $\tilde f(s_i)\in p^{-1}(U)$, and $p^{-1}(U)=\bigcup V_{\alpha}$.

Comment: $p(\tilde f(s_i))\in U$ since $f(s_i)\in U$?

Comment: yes, $p(\tilde f(s_i))=f(s_i)$ since $\tilde f$ lifts $f$.